# Galois theory - permutations of roots

Tags: galois-theory

In all the texts on Galois theory I've looked at so far, when they talk about permutations of roots, they begin by giving an example of relations satisfied by the roots, show that these relations still hold after certain permutations are applied to the roots, then generalise this by saying that any relation satisfied by the roots will still hold after this permutation is applied to it. I don't understand how this generalisation is justified.

For example, consider the polynomial $x^2-4x+1=0$. Its roots are $2+\sqrt3$ and $2-\sqrt3$. These roots satisfy the relations $AB=1$ and $A+B=4$. In either of these equations, swapping A and B gives another true equation. My problem is that they will then say 'therefore any algebraic equation with rational coefficients relating A and B is still true if A and B are swapped and the Galois group of the polynomial is a cyclic group of order 2 (since the permutations that leaves the equations unchanged are a swap and the identity)'. How does it follow from two examples that all possible algebraic equations involving A and B are unchanged when A and B are swapped?

Comment: Can you give an example of a text that says this?  I'm guessing you are misreading what the texts are saying, or what you are just reading is just a vague motivational discussion and is not meant to be taken as rigorous.

Comment: Consider for instance the polynomial $x^2-1$.  Its roots are $A=1$ and $B=-1$, which satisfy $AB=-1$ and $A+B=0$, and these are invariant under swapping $A$ and $B$.  But it is not true you can swap $A$ and $B$ in an arbitrary polynomial equation with rational coefficients (for instance, $A=1$ is true and has rational coefficients, but $B=1$ is false).  So it's definitely NOT correct to deduce this in your example without doing more work and using some special facts about the polynomial.

Comment: Here is an example of a text that says this, or at least that I interpreted to say it. http://pages.uoregon.edu/koch/Galois.pdf On page 43, it talks about the set of relations satisfied by the roots of a polynomial. It says that for the polynomial $X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1=0$, the set of permutations of the roots is isomorphic to $Z_6$. This follows from permutations of a set of relations given on page 42. It then says permuting any relation by one of these permutations gives another relation. So they have generalised the permutations  for the relations on page 42 to all relations

Comment: Yeah, that's just informal motivation, and they haven't actually proven that those are the only relations between the roots you have to worry about.

Comment: The problem isn't that there might be more relations. The problem is them saying that all relations can be permuted by the permutations given on page 42. It's not the only source that says this sort of thing either. On wikipedia, for example, which is where I got my original example from, it says that for that example, every possible algebraic equation still holds if the two roots are swapped. (I know wikipedia isn't a reliable source, but never mind).

Comment: I would note that Wikipedia does not contain the word "therefore" that you wrote.  Instead, it just says "Furthermore, it is true, but far less obvious...".  That is, the statement about general relations does not _follow_ from the two example relations; they're just examples to illustrate what's going on.

Comment: As an illustration, can you find an algebraic but **non-commutative** relation for the roots of say $\Phi_5(x) = 1+x^2+x^3+x^4$ staying true under any $\sigma \in Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_5)/\mathbb{Q})$ (but not under any permutation of those roots) ? @EricWofsey

Comment: @user1952009: I have no idea what you mean by "non-commutative"...

Comment: @EricWofsey $AB=1, A+B=4$ are commutative relations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Future me here. I've just rediscovered this post, and because I have nothing better to do, I will answer it with the answer I would have liked to receive. I'm still not an expert on Galois theory, but at least I know the answer to this question now!

So, firstly, the generalisation isn't justified. I was correct in saying it was a non-sequitur. However, the generalisation is nevertheless true.

Given a multivariate polynomial P(a,b,c...), if the coefficients are from one field and a,b,c etc. are constants are from an extension of that field (this is important - in the example I gave in the question, the coefficients are rational but $2 + \sqrt 3$ and $2 - \sqrt 3$ are irrational), and the equation P(a,b,c)=0 is true, then we may permute a,b,c... in certain ways and the resulting equation will still be true. And compositions of these permutations will also yield another valid permutation, meaning the permutations form a group. Technically, it's even true if the polynomial's arguments and its coefficients are from the same field. In an equation such as $2(3)^2+4(2)-26=0$, the group of permutations consists only of the identity element (i.e. the permutation of not swapping any of the arguments).

The same group obtained for P(a,b,c...) will apply to any other polynomial expression containing a,b,c... Another way to think of this is the permutations can be applied to the extension field and will preserve the base field. It may seem obvious that if we have an extension field containing things like $2+\sqrt3$ and $2-\sqrt3$ then swapping such things won't affect the subfield of rational numbers, since their elements don't involve irrational terms. But don't forget that a number such as 2 could be written in terms of irrationals. For example, we have $4 = (2-\sqrt3) + (2+\sqrt3)$. Such expressions are just polynomial expressions, like the ones discussed earlier - 4 here is just the coefficient of the zero power moved to the other side of the equation. The point is that certain permutations can be carried out on such expressions and result in another true expression. So, we can swap $2-\sqrt3$ and $2+\sqrt3$ and we get $4 = (2+\sqrt3) + (2-\sqrt3)$, which is still true. So any algebraic expression that we can use to represent the number 4 in terms of elements from the extension field will still be equal to 4 if a valid permutation is applied.

Answer (score 5):

[Turning my comments into an answer]

You're totally right that it doesn't follow in any obvious way.  When texts say things like this, they are just giving an informal overview of how Galois theory works, and are not being completely rigorous yet.

Consider for instance the polynomial $x^2−1$. Its roots are $A=1$ and $B=−1$, which satisfy $AB=−1$ and $A+B=0$, and these are invariant under swapping $A$ and $B$. But it is not true you can swap $A$ and $B$ in an arbitrary polynomial equation with rational coefficients (for instance, $A=1$ is true and has rational coefficients, but $B=1$ is false). So it's definitely NOT correct to deduce this in your example without doing more work and using some special facts about the polynomial.

The typical way you justify a statement like this rigorously is by looking at extension fields and using some ring theory.  For instance, in your example, you can consider the field $\mathbb{Q}(A)$.  Since the polynomial $x^2-4x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ (this is the step that doesn't work for $x^2-1$), there is an isomorphism $f:\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-4x+1)\to\mathbb{Q}(A)$ sending $x$ to $A$.  But there is also an isomorphism $g:\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-4x+1)\to\mathbb{Q}(B)$ sending $x$ to $B$ by the same reasoning.  The composition $h=g\circ f^{-1}:\mathbb{Q}(A)\to\mathbb{Q}(B)$ is then an isomorphism sending $A$ to $B$.  But in fact $\mathbb{Q}(A)=\mathbb{Q}(B)$ in this case, so $h$ is an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ sending $A$ to $B$.  You can show that $h$ also sends $B$ to $A$, so it swaps them.  Now if $p(x,y)$ is a polynomial with rational coefficients such that $p(A,B)=0$, we find that $$0=h(0)=h(p(A,B))=p(h(A),h(B))=p(B,A).$$  That is, the equation $p(A,B)=0$ remains true when you swap $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks. That helps a lot. Now I have a second question - I'm curious to know how Galois himself would have approached the problem. My understanding is that he didn't formulate it in terms of group theory/ ring theory.

Comment: Also, I take it that any root can be sent to any other root, but the roots of a function do not always have the full set of permutations (compositions of isomorphisms), so when would a composition of isomorphisms not be valid?

Comment: My understanding is that Galois would have used basically the same argument as the one I gave here, just with the ring theory formalism replaced by explicit arguments about polynomials.  Any element of $\mathbb{Q}(A)$ can be written uniquely in the form $rA+s$ for $r,s\in\mathbb{Q}$ (you can prove this directly using the irreducibility of $x^2-4x+1$), and so $h$ is the map sending $rA+s$ to $rB+s$.  The uniqueness of these representations and the fact that $A$ and $B$ are both roots of $x^2-4x+1$ then proves that this $h$ preserves addition and multiplication.

Comment: If your polynomial is irreducible, then any root can be sent to any other root.  However, this is perfectly compatible with not being able to use _every_ permutation.  Consider the example of $X^6+X^5+X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1$ you mentioned above.  In that case you can use only certain special permutations of the roots, but given any two roots $A$ and $B$, you can still find one of those special permutations that sends $A$ to $B$.

Comment: To be more explicit, suppose you have three roots $A$, $B$, and $C$, and you are only allowed to cyclically permute all three (so for instance you can do $A\to B\to C\to A$ but you can't just swap $A$ and $B$).  Then you can still take any one root to any one other.  To send $A$ to $B$, you use $A\to B \to C\to A$.  To send $A$ to $C$, you use $A\to C\to B\to A$.  And similarly in all the other cases.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Please allow me one - possibly trivial - question: By which argument or theorem does it follow, that for any irreducible polynom $P(X)$ with root $A$ over $K$ there is an isomorphism $f:K[X]/P(X) \rightarrow K(A)$ which sends $X$ to $A$? With $X$ you mean the monic polynom of degree 1 $X$? What does this isomorphism look like (which sends polynomials to numbers and vice versa)?

Comment: @HansStricker: By the universal property of $K[X]$ there exists a unique homomorphism $K[X]\to K(A)$ that is the identity on $K$ and sends $X$ to $A$.  This homomorphism is surjective since $K$ and $A$ generate $K(A)$ as a ring.  The kernel is the ideal of polynomials that vanish when evaluated at $A$.  Since $P(X)$ is irreducible, the ideal it generates is maximal, so the kernel must be generated by $P(X)$ (it cannot be larger).

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thanks a lot. It may be obvious, but for the sake of explicitness: the $X$ that is sent to $A$ is a monic polynomial of degree 1? ("Of course, what else?" you may say.)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @EricWofsey:  Would you mind giving this comment as an answer to this question of mine: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957913/isomorphism-between-kx-px-and-ka-for-a-a-root-of-the-irreducible-pol ? If you wish, I can do it for you - citing you. (It will be interesting to see that and how it is equivalent to other answers - only using different terms.)

Comment: What I wrote is practically identical to the answer that is already there...

Comment: @EricWofsey The example you gave is misleading as $A=1$ is effectively $A=-B$, which is indeed correct under the permutation $A —>B$.