# Isomorphism between $K[X]/P(X)$ and $K(A)$ for $A$ a root of the irreducible polynomial $P(X)$ over $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

I'm afraid the answer to this question should be clear to anyone who knows a little bit of algebra, field theory, field extensions, and polynomials.

In his [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2016356/1792) to a question about [Galois theory and permutations of roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016319/galois-theory-permutations-of-roots), Eric Wofsey writes:

> Since the polynomial $x^2−4x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$,
>   there is an isomorphism
>   $f:\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2−4x+1)\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}(A)$ sending $x$ to
>   $A$

where $A$ is a root of $x^2−4x+1$.

My questions are:

1. By which argument or theorem does this follow, resp. more generally:
   For any irreducible polynomial P(X) with root $A$ over a field $K$
   there is an isomorphism $f:K[X]/P(X)\rightarrow K(A)$ which sends
   $X$ to $A$?
2. With $X$ the monic polynomial of degree 1, $X$, is meant?
3. What does the isomorphism look like (which sends polynomials to
   numbers)?

Comment: Eric should be around here. If you know higher algebra in the sense of van der Waarden, it will all be clear.

Comment: Please give me a hint where to look at. How do I construct the isomorphism?

Comment: Let $\pi:K[X]\to K[X]/(P(X))$ be the canonical projection. As $P(X)$ is irreducible, $L:=K[X]/(P(X))$ is a field. Clearly $K$ embeds in $L$, and $L$ is generated, as a ring, by $K$ and $\pi(X)$. The equalities $0=\pi(P(X))=P(\pi(X))$ show that $\pi(X)$ is a root of $P(X)$ in $L$.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: Would you mind giving this comment as an answer? (It will be interesting to see that and how it is equivalent to other answers - only using different terms.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $L$ be an extension field of $K$ and let $\alpha\in L$. The substitution mapping $\phi:K[x]\rightarrow L$ with $\phi:f\mapsto f(\alpha)$ is ring homomorphism, which is surjective if the mapping is restricted to the image $K(\alpha)$. The kernel of the mapping is the ideal $\langle g\rangle$, where $g\in K[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$. By the homomorphism theorem, we obtain the isomorphism $\psi:K[x]/\langle g\rangle\rightarrow K(\alpha)$ given by $f+\langle g\rangle \mapsto f(\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit.** The proof being very easy, the point is to phrase the statement as clearly as possible.

> Let $K$ be a field, $X$ an indeterminate, and $P(X)\in K[X]$ an irreducible polynomial. Then
>
> (a) $L:=K[X]/(P(X))$ is a field,
>
> (b) if we write $\pi:K[X]\to L$ for the canonical projection and identify $\pi(K)$ to $K$ (noting that $\pi$ is injective on $K$), then we have $L=K[\pi(X)]$, and $\pi(X)$ is a root of $P(X)$ in $L$,
>
> (c) if $M$ is any extension of $K$ containing a root $\alpha$ of $P(X)$, then there is a unique $K$-linear embedding of $L$ in $M$ mapping $\pi(X)$ to $\alpha$.

*Proof.* (a) and the fact that $\pi$ is injective on $K$ are clear. To prove (b) it suffices to observe that, for any polynomial $Q(X)=a_nX^n+\cdots+a_0$ in $K[X]$ we have
$$
\pi(Q(X))=\pi(a_nX^n+\cdots+a_0)=\pi(a_n)\pi(X)^n+\cdots+\pi(a_0)
$$
$$
=a_n\pi(X)^n+\cdots+a_0=Q(\pi(X))
$$
because we have identified $\pi(K)$ to $K$. To prove (c) note that there is a unique $K$-algebra morphism from $K[X]$ to $M$ mapping $X$ to $\alpha$, and that this morphism factors through $L$.

**Previous answer**

Let $\pi:K[X]\to K[X]/(P(X))$ be the canonical projection.

As $P(X)$ is irreducible, $L:=K[X]/(P(X))$ is a field.

Clearly $K$ embeds in $L$, and $L$ is generated, as a ring, by $K$ and $\pi(X)$.

The equalities $0=\pi(P(X))=P(\pi(X))$ show that $\pi(X)$ is a root of $P(X)$ in $L$.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>Eric Wofsey in a [comment to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016319/galois-theory-permutations-of-roots/2016356?noredirect=1#comment6107033_2016356) gave this answer:</sup>

---

By the universal property of $K[X]$ there exists a unique homomorphism $K[X]\rightarrow K(A)$ that is the identity on $K$ and sends [the polynomial] $X$ to [the number] $A$.

This homomorphism is surjective since $K$ and $A$ generate $K(A)$ as a ring.

The kernel is the ideal of polynomials that vanish when evaluated at $A$. Since $P(X)$ is irreducible, the ideal it generates is maximal, so the kernel must be generated by $P(X)$ (it cannot be larger).